# How can I change the size of font in texbox in ultratoolbarsmanager, using Infragistics?

Tags: c#, infragistics

I'm using Net Advantages 2009.2. I have this problem in windows form and I want a large font size inside the texbox. Can anyone help me ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the Designer, select the TextBoxTool item, and resize it.

If you are building the UI with code, then:

```
textBoxTool1.InstanceProps.Width = 114;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about the text size of the textbox, this I can not find. I've asked wrong.

Comment: In Designer, select the TextBoxTool item, and edit Appearance/FontData/SizeInPoints from the Properties pane.  In code, textBoxTool1.Appearance.FontData.SizeInPoints = 20;.

Comment: It isn't working in Properties pane. I also tried this in code `this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Tools["txtCmimTot"].SharedProps.AppearancesLarge.Appearance.FontData.SizeInPoints = 30;` but didn't work. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @user751162: I'm not sure how to only change the size of the TextBox tool item, without affecting all of the other tools in the toolbar.  Will this.ultraToolbarsManager.Appearance.FontData.SizeInPoints = 30; meet your requirements?

Comment: It doesn't because this texbox I use to present the price, and I want price to be bigger than others. Do you know any other form how to do this, I also tried with label but didn't work.

Comment: @user751162: I don't know of a way to change the size/font of an individual item in a toolbar.  Maybe you could have 2 ToolBars, one in "small" size and one "large"?